# PrestaShop Modules page is loading very slowly

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a website based on PrestaShop 1.6. For some unknown reason the Module page in the backend is loading very slowly, in about 2-3 minutes. All the other pages in the backend load fast.

[image: A screenshot showing how long the pages take to load]

Do you have any ideas how to handle this issue?

Comment: Not familiar with prestashop , what does module contains? what kind of functions? You could certainly try to comment out and reload if it is your code.

Comment: Small english improvements. Ending the question with an actual question.

Comment: It is the page with installed modules, like http://joxi.ru/nAyzMwVTj14prZ

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can`t see bigger image. Lets go to prestashop/config/defines.inc file. Search for word: PROFILLING and enable it. Now refresh that page and you may see all information about loading. And you will find that bastard who is loading 2-3 minutes ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a know issue of slow a backend in prestashop 1.6. Here is the fix: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/commit/7e891c594e3cc8b48aea0a57ed674189abc19493. It will be merged in version 1.6.1.2